# REST-request yields error because Jira thinks that required field is missing

Tags: json, rest, jira

I'm trying to create a Jira-issue via `REST`. My request looks like this:

```
Method: POST
Content-Type: application/json
Body: '{"fields":{"project":"ID"}}'
```

The response I get looks like this

```
{"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"project":"project is required"}}
```

which is strange, since I'm providing a project in my request. Does anyone see what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are sending an incorrect JSON to JIRA, according to [JIRA documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/) an [issue](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e2592) is formed like

```
"fields": {
    "project": {
        "id": "10000"
    },
    "summary": "something's wrong",
    "issuetype": {
        "id": "10000"
    },
    "assignee": {
        "name": "homer"
    }
}
```

but you are sending

```
{
    "fields": {
        "project": "ID"
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like i should have just get rid of the first and last `{}`...Thanks anyways :D